# JSF f:selectItems set item selected

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, selectonemenu

I have a `<f:selectItems>` as follows:

```
<p:selectOneMenu id="anios">
    <f:selectItems value="#{pruebaCalendarBean.anios}" var="anio" itemLabel="#{anio}" itemValue="#{anio}"  />
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

anios is defined as:

```
String[] anios = new String[]{"2014","2015","2016","2017"};
```

The value selected is 2014, but I want that is 2016. How to do this? I'm using Primefaces.

Comment: You must set the `value` attribute on the f:selectItems tag

Comment: You missed to set the `value` attribute in your `<p:selectOneMenu>`.

Answer (score 0):

You must include the attribute "value" in the element "selectOneMenu". Something like that:

```
<p:selectOneMenu id="anios" value="#{pruebaCalendarBean.anioSeleccionado}">
    <f:selectItems value="#{pruebaCalendarBean.anios}" var="anio" itemLabel="#{anio}"       itemValue="#{anio}"  />
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

Then in your bean (pruebaCalendarBean) you must define a new attribute, in this case "anioSeleccionado" that represents the selected value in the dropdown